# Retrofit 2 Posting with apikey?

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2

This is my interface:

```
public interface ApiInterface {
@GET("solicitation/all")
Call<SolicitationResponse> getAllNews(@Query("X-Authorization") String apiKey);

@POST("solicitation/create ")
Call<Solicitation> createSolicitation(@Body Solicitation solicitation);
}
```

And this is the MainActivity code to create a new solicitation:

```
    Solicitation solicitation = new Solicitation("xx", "list", "31", "32", "description goes here", "file goes here", "userid goes here", "203120312");

    ApiInterface apiService = ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiInterface.class);

    Call<Solicitation> call = apiService.createSolicitation(solicitation);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<Solicitation>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Solicitation> call, Response<Solicitation> response) {
            Log.d("Response::", "Success!");
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Solicitation> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.e("Response::", "Fail!!");
        }
    });
```

The problem is, as you've seen above on the query I use an api key. `@Query("X-Authorization")`.

It seems I can't do the same to the @Body.

Is there a way to insert the api key there like in the query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

just add the Query separate by comma

```
Call<Solicitation> createSolicitation(@Query("X-Authorization") String apiKey, @Body Solicitation solicitation);
```

or in header

```
Call<Solicitation> createSolicitation(@Header("X-Authorization") String apiKey, @Body Solicitation solicitation);
```

or you need an interceptor to insert the header

```
OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();  
httpClient.addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {  
    @Override
    public Response intercept(Interceptor.Chain chain) throws IOException {
        Request original = chain.request();

        // Request customization: add request headers
        Request.Builder requestBuilder = original.newBuilder()
                .header("X-Authorization", "YOUR AUTH KEY"); // <-- this is the important line

        Request request = requestBuilder.build();
        return chain.proceed(request);
    }
});

OkHttpClient client = httpClient.build();
```

#### usage

```
Call<Solicitation> call = apiService.createSolicitation("YOUR API KEY",solicitation);
```

Comment: Isn't that going to screw up when I call the method createSolicitation ? Like it's going to ask for the string apiKey? (Will test when I get home )

Comment: Is X-Authorization into header??